# bifurcate count basis datetime in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R.

DF

```
ID          Datetime                Value
T-1         2020-01-01 15:12:14     10
T-2         2020-01-01 00:12:10     20
T-3         2020-01-01 03:11:11     25
T-4         2020-01-01 14:01:01     20
T-5         2020-01-01 18:07:11     10
T-6         2020-01-01 20:10:09     15
T-7         2020-01-01 15:45:23     15
```

By utilizing the above-mentioned dataframe, I want to bifurcate the count basis month and time bucket considering the `Datetime`.

Required Output:

```
Month                   Count              Sum
Jan-20                   7                 115
12:00 AM to 05:00 AM     2                 45
06:00 AM to 12:00 PM     0                 0
12:00 PM to 03:00 PM     1                 20
03:00 PM to 08:00 PM     3                 35
08:00 PM to 12:00 AM     1                 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bin the hours of the day by using `hour` from the `lubridate` package and then `cut` from base R, before summarizing with dplyr.

Here, I am assuming that your Datetime column is actually in a date-time format and not just a character string or factor. If it is, ensure you have done `DF$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(DF$Datetime))` first to convert it.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF$bins <- cut(lubridate::hour(DF$Datetime), c(-1, 5.99, 11.99, 14.99, 19.99, 24))
levels(DF$bins) <- c("00:00 to 05:59", "06:00 to 11:59", "12:00 to 14:59", 
                     "15:00 to 19:59", "20:00 to 23:59")

newDF <- DF %>% 
         group_by(bins, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
         summarise(Count = length(Value), Total = sum(Value))
```

This gives the following result:

```
newDF
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   bins           Count Total
#>   <fct>          <int> <dbl>
#> 1 00:00 to 05:59     2    45
#> 2 06:00 to 11:59     0     0
#> 3 12:00 to 14:59     1    20
#> 4 15:00 to 19:59     3    35
#> 5 20:00 to 23:59     1    15
```

And if you want to add January as a first row (though I'm not sure how much sense this makes in this context) you could do:

```
newDF %>% 
summarise(bins = "January", Count = sum(Count), Total = sum(Total)) %>% bind_rows(newDF)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   bins           Count Total
#>   <chr>          <int> <dbl>
#> 1 January            7   115
#> 2 00:00 to 05:59     2    45
#> 3 06:00 to 11:59     0     0
#> 4 12:00 to 14:59     1    20
#> 5 15:00 to 19:59     3    35
#> 6 20:00 to 23:59     1    15
```

Incidentally, the reproducible version of the data I used for this was:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(1:7, .Label = c("T-1", "T-2", "T-3", 
"T-4", "T-5", "T-6", "T-7"), class = "factor"), Datetime = structure(c(1577891534, 
1577837530, 1577848271, 1577887261, 1577902031, 1577909409, 1577893523
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Value = c(10, 
20, 25, 20, 10, 15, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I have a date `2020-01-01 03:45:04` which is falling in bin `00:00 to 05:59' but it should be fall into `15:00 to 19:59`.

Comment: @VectorJX why should it fall into 15:00 to 19:59? These are 24 hour times

Comment: @VectorJX for example, you have `2020-01-01 15:45:23` as one of your times, so surely `2020-01-01 03:45:04` refers to 3:45 am?

Comment: Sorry, My bad. Actually I'm fetching this data from MySQL using `RMySQL` library but I don't know there is difference between MySQL datetime when fetch to R (For Example, For a particular `ID` the MySQL timestamp is `2020-02-04 20:24:13` but in R dataframe it is showing `2020-02-04 14:54:13` :(

Comment: @VectorJX perhaps you need to adjust / convert the time zone? Perhaps R is converting from UTC to your local time zone or vice versa?

Comment: How to convert it to GMT+5:30

Comment: DF$Datetime <- DF$Datetime + lubridate::hours(5) + lubridate::minutes(30)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207211/discussion-between-vector-jx-and-allan-cameron).